# Eclipse Doesn't List Classes Within Java Packages

Tags: java, eclipse, package

Usually when I'm typing a Java import statement in Eclipse or otherwise referencing a class via the packages that it is in, Eclipse shows a context menu with a list of all classes within that package. There have been several times, however, that it would only shows subpackages within a package and would not show classes within that package.

Does anyone know why this is? It sounds like a setting/preference was changed, but I never knowingly changed anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two types of import dialogs. If you start typing a class name, it will search all packages and list possible matching classes. If you start typing a package, it will list all classes and sub packages within the package you're typing.

Sometimes you need to press `Ctrl+space` in order to cycle to the desired dialog.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I didn't realize that there were 3 different categories of proposals, not just on/off. (Default, Template, SWT Template). Only the Default shows me anything, so I must have been periodically cycling on and off of it (thus the appearance that it periodically stopped working).

Comment: I actually don't like this cycling behaviour and normally turn it off. See my response to see how to do that...

Answer (score 2):

You generally should not need to do imports yourself. As you type your code if you use code assist     `( ctrl + space)`  it will show you possible matches and when you hit the enter it will automatically import what you have selected.

Also `( ctrl+ shift + o )` will help you optimize your imports by removing unused ones and sort the needed ones.

for your q : If you still want to do it yourself, it may be a bug if it sometimes work and sometimes does not (which is possible but still unlikely)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to check the "auto completion proposal settings". In eclipse you can define, which kind of proposals you want to see. By default you have several pages of proposals.

Check `Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/ContentAssist/Advanced` to see all configurated pages of proposals, and to see which kinds of proposals they are containing.

I'm not sure whether this is the answer to your question, but it might be helpful to know, where to configure those settings... :)

Comment: This didn't fix my problem, but I did end up using it to disable the SWT Template, so thanks!